# How does one internalize the delayed reward of exercise?

Tags: motivation, exercise, reward

For the past few years my target has been to work out every morning (resistance training). On average I have only made it to the gym around 2 out of every 5 mornings. On days on which I do make it, I feel hugely improved mood and productivity. So,

- What is the current state of research at the intersection of delayed reward and exercise?
- Can motivation can be improved short- or long-term?

Comment: You should try framing this a bit more from a scientific perspective as opposed to a personal perspective, otherwise [you risk this question getting closed](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/502/21).

Comment: It might be worth asking this on http://fitness.stackexchange.com/ instead of here if you were after a personal rather than scientific answer